# how do I allow only one session to Spring REST web service at one time?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have a spring REST web service URL `http://localhost:8080/MySpringRestService/callSome`

How can I restrict concurrent access to web service.

My requirement is to allow only one request to web service at one time.

Any kind of help would be appreciate.

Comment: As with any Java method, you could synchronize the REST controller handler method. But this will likely give terrible performance. I recommend revisiting your design, looking to synchronize a small portion of the code rather than the whole handler.

Comment: Thank you kiwiron, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks kiwiron.
It works.

Sample code is

```
@RequestMapping(value = RestURIConstants.GET_BALANCE_URL, 
method = RequestMethod.POST)
public synchronized @ResponseBody RESSmppModel getBalance(
        @RequestBody REQSmppModel reqSmppModel) throws Exception {

       // TODO: Code
}
```

But , the performance is not good.